# Play Framework 2.5 Loading Application

Tags: playframework, actor

I would like to know how I could get a reference to the Play's ActorSystem with the Play Framework 2.5. From the official documentation, it states that I could inject the ActorSystem in my controller using the @Inject annotation, but I would like to refrain from using this. Is there an alternate way where I could get a reference to the ActorSystem? Any suggestions?

From the API, I can see that there is this AhcWSComponents and this contains the ActorSystem the Materializer that I need, but if I extend this, I should override a plethora of stuff which I do not want. So please give me some suggestions on how I could get a reference to the Play's ActorSystem without the need for using the @Inject annotation!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what's wrong with injecting ActorSystem?

Comment: I would like to have it compile time injected rather than at runtime!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Play provides some support for compile time DI of the built-in components such as the `ActorSystem`. Here is the [trait](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.BuiltInComponents).

You will need to configure an [ApplicationLoader](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaCompileTimeDependencyInjection#Application-entry-point).